# Plot auto_arima predictions on top of actual values

Tags: python, pmdarima

I am still quite new to python and I can't figure out how to do this:

I have a pandas dataframe (data) with two columns: date and values (integers).
I feed this dataframe into an `auto_arima` method.

```
stepwise_model = auto_arima(data, start_p=1, start_q=1,
                   test='adf',
                 max_p=2, max_q=2, m=7,
                   start_P=0, seasonal=True,
                 d=None, D=1, trace=True,
                   error_action='ignore',  
                   suppress_warnings=True, 
                   stepwise=True)
plt.plot(data,color='r')
plt.plot(stepwise_model.predict(),color='g')
plt.show()
```

My objective would be to plot the actual values and overlap the values that the model would generate, in order to compare both lines.
However, my `predict` method only gives me ten values.

If I set:

```
plt.plot(stepwise_model.predict(0,len(data)),color='g')
```

It gives me an error saying that

```
raise ValueError('Prediction must have `end` after `start`.')
```

How can I do this?
Maybe there is another method than using `predict` to plot the correct values?

Answer (score 0):

The ARIMA model here is a different implementation then e.g. statsmodels. The `predict()` method only takes a single parameter to define the length of the forecast which is by default 10. Instead of:

`plt.plot(stepwise_model.predict(0,len(data)),color='g')`

You need to give only the amount of time steps you want to predict (no start or end like in statsmodels):

`plt.plot(stepwise_model.predict(len(data)),color='g')`

This is the model you have:
https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.ARIMA.html

And this is it's `predict()` method:
https://alkaline-ml.com/pmdarima/modules/generated/pmdarima.arima.ARIMA.html#pmdarima.arima.ARIMA.predict

If you want to plot the predicted data over the actual data, you can do this here:

```
plt.plot(stepwise_model.predict(len(data)),color='g')
plt.plot(actual_data)
plt.show()
```

Everything you put before `plt.show()` will be in the same figure.